# Maven: does dependency management mean that I don't have to ship libraries (such as log4j)?

Tags: maven, download, dependencies, log4j

I'm new to Maven. I'm trying to build a test project, which includes log4j.
My java class is just a 'hello world' with an import for log4j like this:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
```

My pom.xml includes the following section:

```
<build>
...
    <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.12</version>
          </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
...
</build>
```

I haven't downloaded log4j jars at this point .....

I run:

```
mvn install.
```

I get:

```
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Compilation failure
App.java:[2,23] package org.apache.log4j does not exist
...
```

So I am obviously misunderstanding how Maven works here....

I thought I should be able to ship (as a minimum) a 'pom.xml' and my code to another user, and Maven should fetch the deps ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to the Maven world ;-)

You have to remove the `<dependencyManagement>` tags, it should work.

This tag is used when you use Maven modules (see the [Maven doc](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management))

Comment: Quick question though - where is the log4j file in the target ??? (after a 'mvn package'...)

Answer (score 1):

If you're shipping a packaged application, you still have to provide the dependencies, usually by bundling them up into the jar using the shade or assembly plugin.

If you're shipping a library for use by other developers, that's where Maven comes in handy. In that case you don't have to provide the dependencies. (If this is the case, you shouldn't depend on log4j directly, but use SLF4J).

Comment: Thanks for this ; actually log4j was just an example, I'm thinking of using this for projects that contain the usual suspects; apache commons, hibernate etc; with the minimum 'description' of the deps needed. Shipping to developers is what I have in mind (or at least somebody building from source, rather than pre-packaged).

Comment: mmh...I'm confused about where that log4j library went: mvn install + mvn package resulted in a compiled jar, but it won't run (missing log4j...) I guess I'll need to read the maven docs some more...

Comment: It won't run by itself, no; that's where you need the shade or assembly plugin. Or you can use the `exec-maven-plugin` which will sort out the classpath for you.

Comment: Thanks again - this other post here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com)/questions/97640/force-maven2-to-copy-dependencies-into-target-lib gets me to where i want to be for now. Cheers.